# Java Regular Expression match one or more characters in list

Tags: java, regex

I have some strings:

- total 19xx.100
- total 19x..100
- total 19..100
- total 19x .100

And I want to separate 19 with ("x" or "." one or more times) and 100.
I tried to use regex:

```
 (x|\.)+
```

to group but it can not match all case above. Which regex can match all case above?

Comment: What is the rule here? What do you mean by "separate"? Replace with space? Try [`replaceAll("\\s*[x.][x.\\s]*", " ")`](https://regex101.com/r/A1iflL/1).

Comment: Show the code snippet.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I want to catch 19 in a group, xx. or x.. or .. or x . in a group and 100 in another group.

Comment: Does [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/A1iflL/2) work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it works well. Thank you. You can add an answer so I can accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(\d+)(\s*[x.][x.\s]*)(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1iflL/2)

**Details**

- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(\s*[x.][x.\s]*)` - Group 2:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `[x.]` - an `x` or `.`
  - `[x.\s]*` - 0+ chars that are either `x`, `.` or whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
public static Matcher split(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(x*)(\\s*)(\\.*)(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    matcher.find();

    return matcher;
}
```

This regex works for test data:

```
19xx.100
19x.100
19..100
19x .100
```

After then `matcher.group(1)` will return `19` and `matcher.group(5)` will return `100`

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you could capture what is before 100 and 100 in 2 capturing groups:

[`(\d+[x. ]+)(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/RLu2Kl/1)

**Explanation**

- Capturing group *(group 1)* `(`
- Match one or more digits `\d+`
- Match one or more times `x`, `.` or whitespace `[x. ]+` using a character class
- Close capturing group `)`
- Capture in a group *(group 2)* one or more digits `(\d+)`